# Problem using patchEntity to update a database record with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am tryin to save an updated record to my database. I am using the code created by bake, but the new information is not saved. I have placed echo statements in my code to see what the value of the information is and it show the correct information, it just does not save it. I am at a loose.

I have tried to change some of the validation rules with no success. Her is the code I have with the echo statements in it.

```
    public function edit() {
        echo $this->request->getData('id').  ' ';
        echo $this->request->getData('price') . ' ';

        $room = $this->Rooms->get($this->request->getData('id'), [
             'contain' => []
          ]);
        echo $room;

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $room = $this->Rooms->patchEntity($room, $this->request->getData());
            echo $room;

            if ($this->Rooms->save($room)) {
                echo $room;
                exit();
                $this->Flash->success(__('The room has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            echo $room;
            exit();
            $this->Flash->error(__('The room could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('room'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

This is what displayed from the echo statements:

```
1 
89.95 

{ "roomnumber": 101, "kingcount": 0, "queencount": 1, "fullcount": 0, "twincount": 0, "kitchenette": 0, "suite": 0, "rooms": 1, "floor": 1, "price": 69.95, "description": "This is a nice room with a single queen size bed and 55 inch flat screen television hung on the wall.", "id": 1 }{ "roomnumber": 101, "kingcount": 0, "queencount": 1, "fullcount": 0, "twincount": 0, "kitchenette": 0, "suite": 0, "rooms": 1, "floor": 1, "price": 89.95, "description": "This is a nice room with a single queen size bed and 55 inch flat screen television hung on the wall.", "id": 1 }{ "roomnumber": 101, "kingcount": 0, "queencount": 1, "fullcount": 0, "twincount": 0, "kitchenette": 0, "suite": 0, "rooms": 1, "floor": 1, "price": 89.95, "description": "This is a nice room with a single queen size bed and 55 inch flat screen television hung on the wall.", "id": 1 }
```

I am hoping for when the information changes it get saved to the database, but it just return to the index page with the old information.

Comment: Check the request type; Cake's forms will often use PUT or PATCH instead of POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for debugging use cakephp debug() or core php print_r() function, don't echos. Read **patchEntity** debug output, if has any error message please post in your question.

**https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/debugging.html**

> I am hoping for when the information changes it get saved to the database, but it just return to the index page with the old information.

Clear cache `bin/cake cache clear_all`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Salines. I used the cakephp debug() function, found the problem and was able to correct it. It is working fine now.