# CakePHP patchEntity() and save() not updating specific fields in database

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model, save

So I have added a few additional fields to an Orders table, **payment_type** and **order_status**.

I have added them to the Accessible array for the related Model, but after a Save(), I'm not seeing the two fields populated in the Database. What could be happening here?

FWIW, here's a print_r() of the Save() return:

```
App\Model\Entity\Order Object
(
   [grand_total] => 99.99
   [payment_type] => Paypal
   [order_status] => Accepted
   [transaction_id] => 123
   [[new]] => 
   [[accessible]] => Array
       (
           [grand_total] => 1
           [payment_type] => 1
           [order_status] => 1
           [transaction_id] => 1
       )

   [[dirty]] => Array
       (
       )

   [[original]] => Array
       (
       )

   [[virtual]] => Array
       (
       )

   [[hasErrors]] => 
   [[errors]] => Array
       (
       )

   [[invalid]] => Array
       (
       )

   [[repository]] => Orders
)
```

Strangely though, when I run this command on my local environment, it updates those columns with no issues. Live server and my local are duplicate repositories, so it must be a database or server config setting? And, I can't find anything in the logs pointing to any errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my live environment ORM cache was still reflecting the old schema.

Until now I had no idea this was a thing, and honestly I'm beyond frustrated not understanding /why/. I'll have to do some reading on this to get a better understanding.

For anyone from the future having the similar issues, cross check your buggy environment's "/tmp/cache/models/" folder and either remove or update the table schema file in question.

Comment: You can use `bin/cake schema_cache clear` command to clear cache for the models. It is advised to clear cache everytime you deploy it on production https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/deployment.html#deploying-an-update

Comment: Or `bin/cake cache clear_all` to clear everything

Comment: Related and similar accepted answer: [Problem using patchEntity to update a database record with cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57457635/8958173)